# .NET Framework 4.5 / .NET Standard 1.0 support in .NET 6

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-4.5, .net-5, .net-6.0

I'm currently developing an application using .NET 5 and aim to migrate it to .NET 6 when fully released.

I'm considering using a library that's implemented in .NET Framework 4.5, which works in .NET 5

Will it still be compatible using .NET 6 & are there any other risks in using such a library in general?

Comment: You need to look into .net Standard.  This provides a "standard" which can be used between the different frameworks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard  But basically you can't develop in pure .Net Framework and expect it to work in .Net 5 or 6.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I said that I want to have information about compatibility and risks. Nevertheless, it's not my library, the only thing I know about the library is that it relay on .Net Framework 4.5. It would be a bunch of work to implement the stuff by myself. In my understanding, the .Net Framework 4.5 implements some version of the .Net Standard and that's why it can work with .Net 5. And it does currently. I don't really know how to determine if this compatibility last in the future or risks of having these depedencies.

Comment: @tobias ah OK, writing answer - thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: .NET 5 and later are actually .NET *Core*. .NET 4.5 itself is out of support and in a few months, all versions below 4.6.2 will be out of support as well. `that's implemented in .NET Framework 4.5, which works in .NET 5` that's not the case. You can't use a .NET Framework library in .NET Core. You can only do so if it targets .NET Standard. And since you *are* moving to .NET Core, there's no reason to target anything less than .NET Standard 2

Comment: `Will it still be compatible using .NET 6 ` no it won't. Whether there are any problems depends on what it does and what APIs it uses. WinForms and WPF APIs were initially added in .NET Core 3.1 for example, with full(ish) support in .NET 5. WebForms was never migrated. Windows specific APIs can work in .NET 5 and later if you use a Windows-specific target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your project is on .NET Framework 4.5 & is "working" in your .NET 5 project, it'll be targeting [.NET Standard 1.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.0.md).

In that case, according to [Microsoft documentation for .NET Standard versioning](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard), **.NET Standard 1.0 will be supported fully in .NET 6.0 as well**.

You should have no issues moving forward with your upgrade.

[image]

---

> Are there other risks?

It would be best to use a more updated library, which does the same functionality as the older library.

Of course, such a library may not exist hence why MSFT tries hard to maintain compatibility.

Other than the library not being able to take advantage of the latest .NET security & performance improvements that have been introduced with newer versions of .NET, you'll be fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238489/discussion-on-answer-by-ermiya-eskandary-net-framework-4-5-net-standard-1-0).